# ClassCastException at Java.lang.String in Android

Tags: android, string, classcastexception

I have no idea why I'm getting it on this line of code (where the arrow is)

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
--->    App selection = (App) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

private ArrayList<String> myarr = new ArrayList<String>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;

//objects = array of whatever you want to add to the list
public MyCustomAdapter(Context context,
        int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    myarr = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

      View row = convertView;
      if(row==null){
       row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent,false);
      }

      ((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.rowtextview)).setText(myarr.get(position));

      return row;
     }
```

This is the arrayadapter that does the work. I'm assuming the problem is in here.

Comment: its a custom class that i had created. i dont understand why i cant cast it to the object that l.getItemAtPosition returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have stored `String` in your `ListView`. It gives the exception because it cannot cast `String` to `App`

**EDIT**
The objects in your `myarr` are displayed in your `ListView`. Those objects are all `String`s. In the line where you get exception you are trying to convert the `String` at `position` to an `App`. It cannot do that so you get the exception. So try this:

```
String selection = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

**EDIT2**
Change `myarr` to

```
private ArrayList<App> myarr = new ArrayList<App>();
```

Change the following line:

```
((TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.rowtextview)).setText(myarr.get(position).getText());
```

Add `App` class:

```
public String getText(){/*...*/}
public void setText(String text){/*...*/}
public String toString(){ /*...*/}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Because I have a custom arrayadapter set up, and a list_row.xml which contains how a row in the list should look like. I understand what you mean but I'm not sure what to look for exactly

Comment: ok its up. give it a glance. and which xml file would you like to see?

Comment: thanks, yeah i figured it out now. unfortunately i need it to be an App type. is there anything i can do in my ListView to help support App class?

Answer (score 0):

if it is custom use like this

```
MyFont f = fontArray[pos];
selected_font = f.getValue();
```